# iMessage no longer working on Mac after AppleID change

Tags: ipad, macbook-pro, messages

I recently just got my first MacBook Air. I already have an iPad mini and I just changed my Apple ID. I had everything set up before I decided to change it and iMessage was working perfectly on both devices. Anyway so after I went through all the hassle of changing my Apple ID when I went back onto my laptop, it won't even let me send a message even though I have set to my new Apple ID.

Comment: When you say it won't let you send, what happens exactly?

Comment: Also go to iMessage menu > Preferences and then click on the Accounts tab. Is your Apple ID listed there? If so is it signed in and enabled?

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of the time when iMessage no longer delivers to a Mac (or iOS device) is due to the time settings where the clock has drifted.

I would work through this checklist as you rule out any account related issues (especially the part about appleid.apple.com to verify the account isn't locked):

- http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3970

It also covers a big reason why messages fail to be delivered even if you can sign in - firewall settings and networking issues between the Mac and the APNS servers that alert your computer a message is coming and help deliver the message itself.